# Best practices for clean domain model

Tags: java, .net, jakarta-ee, architecture

I'm looking for some best practices for developing a clean domain object model.  By 'clean', I mean a domain (or business) model that isn't cluttered up with a bunch of DB persistence, xml/json serialization/deserialization, dependency injection stuff.  For example, I've read thru several 'how-to' tutorials about implementing the REST API.  When they all get to the point of implementing the 'model', they all end up having some annotations about transforming from the 'pojo/poco' to the xml/json view via [XmlAttribute],  or making the field be more user friendly in the UI via [Display/Display Type] attribute.  The platform doesn't matter, I've seen the cluttering in the Java world (not familiar with other scripting languages).

I'm aware of the Data Transfer Object design pattern as those objects could use these attributes, but is this the only method?  DTO seems like it would require a lot of object mapping to/from view to the business layer.  If that's what it takes to have a clean domain layer, then great, just looking for feedback.

Thanks

Comment: WCF will infer data members if a DTO is left un-annotated by default with 4.0 (at least). Always better to be explicit than assume some magic will happen otherwise though, why the need for implicit exposure?

Comment: I don't understand the down-vote. It has become a trend on SO to down-vote questions that have dense text.

Comment: @aquaraga - I didn't downvote, but your comment would be a better fit for MSO. From my experience - the trend on SO is to downvote questions that show little use-specific context or effort. This is especially true of questions that tag multiple languages. If you don't know which language your code is in then you should probably be posting on PSE. My constituents on MSO may or may not agree.

Comment: @M.Babcock I definitely can see that the OP has done some research before asking this question. Plus there is an 'architecture' tag on SO, which is meant to encompass the whole gamut of language-agnostic questions. The OP probably thought that Java and .NET developers/architects could give reasonable answers: which it quite turns out to be (Will Hartung has given an answer, using a Java example).

Answer (score 2):

The simple truth is that all of that "annotation clutter" rose up out of a rejection of all the "XML clutter".

Taking both JPA and JAXB in Java as examples, all of those annotations can be replaced by external XML files describing the same meta data for the underlying frameworks. In both of these cases, the frameworks offer "ok" defaults for unannotated data, but the truth is few are really satisfied with the Convention over Configuration default mappings the frameworks offer, and thus more explicit configuration needs to be done.

And all of that configuration has to be captured somewhere, somehow.

For many folks and many applications, the embedded meta data via annotations is a cleaner and easier to use than the external XML mapping methods.

In the end, from a Java perspective, the domain models are "just" objects, the annotations have no bearing, in general, outside of the respective frameworks. But in truth, there's always some coupling with the frameworks, and they have a tendency to influence implementation details within the model. These aren't particularly glaring, but the simple fact is that when there may be two ways to model something, and one way is "more friendly" to the framework, for many that's enough to tilt the decision to go in that direction rather than fighting for purity above the framework.